# Why do the references to my constants disappear when I try to put my code inside a class in Swift?

Tags: class, swift

I am trying to use an NSTimer in Swift and I am having problems because I wrote my code in a new swift file, so it does not inherit from NSObject. It is my (barely) understanding that the NSTimer needs a selector which requires this inheritance. So it seems like I should take all the code after the imports and wrap the whole thing in a class definition (this has other advantages too now that I think about it). But it is not working. 
For example:

```
var recordSettings = [
AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatAppleLossless,
AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Max.toRaw(),
AVEncoderBitRateKey : 320000,
AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0]
let nameFileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:"somePath")
let nameRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: nameFileUrl, settings: recordSettings, error: &error)
```

That works just fine. But...

```
class someClass: NSObject {
   var recordSettings = [
   AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatAppleLossless,
   AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Max.toRaw(),
   AVEncoderBitRateKey : 320000,
   AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
   AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0]
   let nameFileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:"somePath")
   let nameRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: nameFileUrl, settings: recordSettings, error: &error)
```

}

gives me a "someClass.Type does not have a member named 'nameFileUrl' " error on the "let nameRecorder" line.  Any variables or constant definitions that I put inside the class aren't seen when I try to call them. I have tried self.nameFileUrl and someClass.nameFileUrl and nothing seems to work. I am assuming it has something to do with scope, but being an idiot I have learned not to trust my own assumptions. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: note that you should capitalize the type definition: `SomeClass` and not `someClass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class SomeClass: NSObject {
    var recordSettings = [
        AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatAppleLossless,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Max.toRaw(),
        AVEncoderBitRateKey : 320000,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
        AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0]

    let nameFileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:"somePath")
    let nameRecorder : AVAudioRecorder?

    override init() {
        var error: NSError?
        nameRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: nameFileUrl, settings: recordSettings, error: &error)
        if nameRecorder == nil {
            println("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

var someClass : SomeClass = SomeClass()
// ... use someClass
```

Your definition of nameRecorder has to be done in a method. Here I do it in the constructor (not necessarily ideal) but you'll get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got it working when I declared the Audio recorder first as an optional "var nameRecorder :AVAudioRecorder?
" and then after I define the recorder in the method I needed to "unpack" the optional so all calls made to the recorder need the "!"  like "nameRecorder!.prepareToRecord()" Thanks for putting me on the right path!